# Running SuperDevMode with a Maven EAR packaged GWT application

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, gwt

I've successfully refactored my typical GWT 2.7 and AppEngine stacked application from a single Maven module into many - I can compile, run the AppEngine dev server and deploy.

I need some guidance as to configure GWT SuperDevMode using the [GWT mojo](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/). Now the client and server components are split into different modules and packaged using a [EAR module](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/), I'm unsure where to start.

The project layout looks something like:

```
/app-client (GWT) - I use the GWT mojo here to compile a client WAR. I used to have everything in here.
/app-core (Shared Code) - JAR
/app-server (Default AppEngine Module) - WAR
/app-auth (Auth AppEngine Module) - WAR
/app-worker (Worker AppEngine Module) - WAR
/app-ear (EAR Package) - I use the AppEngine mojo here for deployment.
pom.xml - parent
```

I assume the GWT mojo must be ran on the `app-ear` module, but how do I provide the `app-client` sources to the run configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mojo's Maven Plugin for GWT does not make it easy to run dev mode in multi-module builds. To get the correct classpath, you need to run the `gwt:run` or `gwt:run-codeserver` goal in your `app-client` module (and to do that you either need to `mvn install` your dependencies –`app-core`– and/or hack around with profiles and the `build-helper-maven-plugin`; see [this POM](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/blob/3f53aa73f1ac60b84132572d47072878ad31b030/modular-webapp/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/__rootArtifactId__-client/pom.xml#L87-L124) for an example, which both requires `mvn install` to resolve the dependency, and uses the `build-helper-maven-plugin` so you can make changes to your shared code without the need for a `mvn install` and restarting dev mode).

FWIW, [`net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin`](https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/) (disclaimer: I'm the author) was created with that use-case in mind from the beginning; so you actually run `gwt:devmode` or `gwt:codeserver` on the parent module and tell it which module(s) is a GWT app and where to generate the `*.nocache.js`.

Comment: Thanks @thomas-broyer, that has helped fix the `gwt:compile` goal, no problems launching the code server. To integrate this with `appengine:devserver`, should it just be a matter of setting the `launcherDir` to write to the `app-ear` target directory?

Comment: Never-mind, that all seems to be working now using that configuration. Thanks for the help, I'm looking forward building GWT 3 apps in the future so keep up the great work!